# Deref and cannot borrow `form` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code: [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45211fe5c8fb534459a707c4389597a8). Form is a wrapper around Contextual which holds a User. It relies on Deref so that `form.value` works instead of having to do `form.0.value` except it fails to compile with the following error. However, if I avoid using deref by uncommenting the line `let mut form = form.0;` then the code works. Why?

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `form` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:64:37
   |
62 |     match form.value {
   |           ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
63 |         Some(ref mut user) => {
64 |             if foo(user.email, &mut form.context) {
   |                                     ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
65 |                 bar(user, &mut form.context);
   |                     ---- first borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `form` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:65:32
   |
62 |     match form.value {
   |           ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
65 |                 bar(user, &mut form.context);
   |                 ---            ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 |
   |                 first borrow later used by call

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

```
use futures::executor::block_on;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

pub struct Form<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Form<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for Form<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

pub struct Contextual<T> {
    pub value: Option<T>,
    pub context: i64,
}

pub struct User<'a> {
    pub email: &'a str,
    pub password: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
  block_on(go());
}

async fn go() {
    let mut form = Form(
        Contextual {
            value: Some(User {
                email: "foo",
                password: "bar",
            }),
            context: 5
        }
    );
    
    // uncomment this line to make this work
    // let mut form = form.0;

    match form.value {
        Some(ref mut user) => {
            if foo(user.email, &mut form.context) {
                bar(user, &mut form.context);
            }
        }
        None => {
        }
    }
}

fn foo(email: &str, context: &mut i64) -> bool {
    true
}

fn bar(user: &User<'_>, context: &mut i64) -> bool {
    true
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the borrow checker works.

Comment: So that question pretty much explains it?